# Detecting a new added product from front end to set a product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

Im using a plugin called Booster plus for Woocommerce which make me able to add a product through a form in front-end,
but I need submit every product of this form as a SPECIFIC CATEGORY
so I have to detect when a new product added and update the category(override the plugin)

Here is the code:

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'new_product_add', 10, 3);
 function new_product_add($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
 if( 
        $old_status != 'publish' 
        && $new_status == 'publish' 
        && !empty($post->ID) 
        && in_array( $post->post_type, 
            array( 'product') 
            )
        ) {
            $term = get_term_by('name', 'فروش پیج اینستاگرام', 'product_cat');
            wp_set_object_terms($product_ID, $term->term_id, 'product_cat');
     }
  }
```

the first part running okay, I mean detecting when a new product is publishing from front end

But updating the category has failed, it automatically set the category to the first category I have created

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `$product_id` that is not defined and should be replaced by `$post->ID` instead

Comment: @CameronA We answered at the same time…